# Inject Docker LABEL into Kubernetes Metadata Annotation

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker image that I'm running in my Kubernetes clusters, the image has a label tag with the repository, thats being added at build time:

```
docker build . --label "repo=<repo_name>" tag <tag>
```

I have a kubenetes deployment that looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: my-cool-app
  name: my-cool-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-cool-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: my-cool-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <imagename>:v1
        name: my-cool-app
        resources: {}
```

I'm wondering is it possible to extract the docker image label, and add that as a metadata label in my kubernetes spec?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to extract it, but you can attach this in the deployment you used. For example if you use [Helm chart](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#variables), you can use one variable for metadate and for image. All you need to do, is to update the value.yaml. It might look like:

value.yaml

```
my-cool-app-tag: v1
```

my-cool-app.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: my-cool-app
  name: my-cool-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-cool-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: my-cool-app
        tag-lable: {{ .value.my-cool-app-tag }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <imagename>:{{ .value.my-cool-app-tag }}
        name: my-cool-app
        resources: {}
```